# mongo university local host error when connecting

Tags: java, mongodb, shell

So I'm taking the M101J class online and I'm trying to start up the "blog" that mongo university supplies to you so you can learn. I had downloaded the zip file, and did the procedures as told on the site: Download Mongoproc, Download the Handout, run the shell and go to  http://localhost:8082. But when I try to do so I get a "This site can’t be reached" error.

My folder:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_FJjPTh2vMrTkRSYl9SZWlVcFk?usp=sharing

Comment: My screen: https://i.gyazo.com/d25e17e5d5a728430b17ddabc81a3e33.mp4

Comment: Hi mike, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of linking to a screengrab, could you instead paste the relevant information into your question. The policy on this site is for [the question to include all relevant information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) rather than relying on external links.